# Error in database query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to create table in MySql through Java program. There seems to be a error in the database query for creating table which I am not able to figure out. This is my java program

```
package Registration;



import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;




public class StartBatch 
{


    public void startBatch(String batch)

    {


    Connection connection=null;

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Batches";

        Statement stmt;

        ResultSet rs1;


        try

        {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");



        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

             stmt=connection.createStatement();

         rs1=stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"+batch+"` (\n" +"  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n" +"  `student` text NOT NULL,\n" +"  `fees` bigint(20) NOT NULL,\n" +"  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n" +") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");

   //The error is in above query     
    }

                     catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

            }

            catch(SQLException e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

            }

            catch (Exception e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

            }

            finally {

            // Always close the database connection.

            try {

            if (connection != null) connection.close();

            }

            catch (SQLException ignored){

            }


        }

    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.sql.ResultSet
    at Registration.StartBatch.startBatch(StartBatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.jsp.CreatedBatch_jsp._jspService(CreatedBatch_jsp.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Netbeans to run this class.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Please post the error which you are getting

Comment: There´s no way to know what´s going on if you dont add extra information like your stacktrace

Comment: connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");   Where is your password for MySQL database ?. MySQL database doesn't allows you to do anything untill you entered the valid password

Comment: statement.executeUpdate doesn't return a ResultSet, returns an int

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int updt;
    updt=stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + batch + " (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, student text NOT NULL, fees bigint(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `executeUpdate()` is used for `insert,delete and update` queries so you should not use this for **creating a table**.

If you want to create a table using [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()) of `Statement or 
PreparedStatement`(mostly recommended) whose return type is void.

Moreover your `stmt.executeUpdate(query)` returns `int` type not `ResultSet` type please go through the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))